# jsonschema2pojo gradle plugin not generate Java classes in subproject

Tags: android, gradle, react-native, jsonschema2pojo

I have React Native Android project with [jsonschema2pojo](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/tree/master/jsonschema2pojo-gradle-plugin) Gradle plugin in root project and in subproject too (located in cd ../node_modules/subproject) with different jsonSchema2Pojo configuration

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':subproject')
}
```

My Android Subproject is standard React Native module library located in ../node_modules.
If I run 'gradlew build' on the root project in subproject Java classes is not generated only in root project.
To generate Java classes in subproject I needs to navigate to subproject directory first:

```
cd ../node_modules/subproject/android
./gradlew generateJsonSchema2PojoForDebug
```

can I run the subproject generateJsonSchema2PojoForDebug task with the root build ?

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that I have `source = files("$rootDir/../json_model")` and when the library is installed in node_modules `source` cannot be found from plugin. This fix the issue:

```
jsonSchema2Pojo {
    // Location of the JSON Schema file(s). This may refer to a single file or a directory of files.
    source = files("$projectDir/../json_model")
}
```